# Filtering multiple ViewModel tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvvm, foreach

I am displaying multiple tables using a ViewModel, each table has `CompanyName`, I am trying to get this looped so that the data shown is foreach `AddCustomersID`, (`AddCustomersID` is the key for the model containing `CompanyName`). This is to display each customers information on separate modals, where as at the moment every customers data appears on each modal.

View:

```
@model Intranet.ViewModels.IntranetViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model.AddCustomers)
{
<div class="modal">
                <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Forename</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.EmployeeInfo)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddCustomers.CompanyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Forename)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Surname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobile)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telephone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ContactInfo)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddCustomers.CompanyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Postcode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telephone)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
...
</div>
}
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace Intranet.ViewModels
{
    public class IntranetViewModel
    {
        public IntranetViewModel()
        {
            AddCustomers = new List<AddCustomers>();
            EmployeeInfo = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
            ContactInfo = new List<ContactInfo>();
...
        }

        public int IntranetViewModelID { get; set;}

        public IEnumerable<AddCustomers> AddCustomers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ContactInfo> ContactInfo { get; set; }
...    
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
private IntranetContext db = new IntranetContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = new IntranetViewModel
            {
                AddCustomers = db.AddCustomers,
                EmployeeInfo = db.EmployeeInfo,
                ContactInfo = db.ContactInfo,
...
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

I have tried using a Javascript filter, however this only works with using `getElementById` on a single table and does not work with `getElementsByClassName` to allow use on multiple tables.

I have also tried using `@using (Html.BeginForm())` dropdown list however for this again I have yet to find a working example for multiple tables.

Is there a way to do this using filtering or even better filter using c# razor when the `@foreach` is called?

Comment: I can not see AddCustomersID in your code. It is not clear what you are trying to do here. You are looping through AddCustomers and inside it your are looping through EmployeeInfo and ContactInfo which are not related with AddCustomers in this model.

Comment: @Arkadiusz AddCustomersID is in the individual models of the different types of customer info e.g. EmployeeInfo Model and ContactInfo Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this by using `.Where<>`, example below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var CIitem in Model.ContactInfo.Where(i => i.AddCustomers.AddCustomersID == item.AddCustomersID))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => CIitem.AddCustomers.CompanyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => CIitem.Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => CIitem.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => CIitem.Postcode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => CIitem.Telephone)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This has specified to only show the `AddCustomersID` of the Modal that has been created.